# Why can't I go to localhost using Laradock?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laradock

I'm getting error: This page isn’t working

I ran the following command inside the Laradock directory yet it's not connecting when I go to localhost. `docker-compose up -d nginx postgres`

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
19433b191832        laradock_nginx       "/bin/bash /opt/star…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   laradock_nginx_1
e7f68a9d841d        laradock_php-fpm     "docker-php-entrypoi…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        9000/tcp                                   laradock_php-fpm_1
3c73fedff4aa        laradock_workspace   "/sbin/my_init"          5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp                       laradock_workspace_1
eefb58598ee5        laradock_postgres    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                     laradock_postgres_1
ea559a775854        docker:dind          "dockerd-entrypoint.…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        2375/tcp                                   laradock_docker-in-docker_1
```

`docker-compose ps` returns these results:

```
$ docker-compose ps
Name                          Command              State                    Ports                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
laradock_docker-in-docker_1   dockerd-entrypoint.sh           Up      2375/tcp                                
laradock_nginx_1              /bin/bash /opt/startup.sh       Up      0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
laradock_php-fpm_1            docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm   Up      9000/tcp                                
laradock_postgres_1           docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                  
laradock_workspace_1          /sbin/my_init                   Up      0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There’s at least six different `localhost` involved here.  Which command are you running, from where, and what result are you getting?

Comment: Sorry i should have been more explicit. I'm talking about port 80, it should be going to the nginx container and then being forwarded to php-fpm container via the default Laradock setup.

Comment: Can you please also make docker-compose up without -d option. And check output in terminal, by starting containers and when you try to open a page in browser. Maybe we will find some kind of errors there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. I edited my docker-compose file volume to be `/local/path/to/default.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available`

This is a problem because nginx looks for default.conf file but the volumes flag was setting sites-available as the file. I thought docker volume would symlink the file into the site-available directory not make it a file.

The correct volume syntax should be:
`/local/path/to/default.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf`